# Bootstrap Switch onclick() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to alert some thing **onclick** of  [Bootstrap Switch Button](http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/).
But every time I do that, nothing fires up.

So I tried **onchange**, and it alert something, but when I added the ajax function for the onchange. It didn't work again.
Here are my codes:

```
<input type='checkbox'  onclick='switchStatus($id,$status)' data-size='mini' name='my-checkbox' $status>
```

Here is the code for my function:

```
function switchStatus(id,status){
          alert(id);

  /*var theID = id;
  var theStatus = status;
  var dataString = "projectID=" + theID + "&status=" + theStatus,
  $.ajax({
      url:    "ajax/updateProjectStatus.php",
      type:   "POST",
      data:   dataString,
      cache:  false,  
      success: function (data){
        alert(data);
      }   
  });*/
}
```

Here's the rest of the code:

```
<?php
      $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * from tbl_project where col_status <> 2");
      $sql->execute();  
        while($result = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
          $id           = $result['projectID'];
          $name         = $result['col_projName'];
          $date         = $result['col_createdDate'];
          $status       = ($result['col_status']==1) ? "checked" : "";
          $sd = "asd";
          echo " 
          <tr>
            <td>$id</td>
            <td>$name</td>
            <td>$date</td>
            <td>
            <input type='checkbox'  onchange='switchStatus($id,$status)'  data-toggle='toggle' $status>
            </td>
            <td>
            <div class='btn-group'  role='group'>
              <input type='button'  value='Manage'  onclick='Xmanage($id,\"$name\")'  class='btn btn-info'>
              <input type='button'  value='Remove'  onclick='Xdelete($id)'                class='btn btn-danger'>
            </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          ";
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: Is there any error on console?

Comment: Console doesn't show any errors.

Comment: First of all, you are using pdo prepare and execute where you can also just use PDO query because there is no external input involved.

Comment: As a check, if you add `echo "something awesome";` before the while loop, does it output anything then? If your query fails because the while loop doesn't run.

Answer (score 0):

On you dataString variable, you end it with a comma, this indicates that a next property is coming, which is not the case.
Replace that with a semicolon and see what that does..

```
  var theID = id;
  var theStatus = status;
  var dataString = "projectID=" + theID + "&status=" + theStatus;
  $.ajax({
      url:    "ajax/updateProjectStatus.php",
      type:   "POST",
      data:   dataString,
      cache:  false,  
      success: function (data){
        alert(data);
      }   
  });
```

Comment: @Juju Where is the $id being set in the input? I see status, but where is $id?